# Why EOF of file not work in my PHP code?

Tags: php

I'm writing a PHP program to read a passwd file like below:

```
  1 misshary:x:1002:1003:Li Han,Li Han,,:/home/misshary:/bin/bash
  2 testuser:x:1003:1004:test user,,,:/home/testuser:/bin/bash
```

And here is my code:

```
        $file = fopen("/path/passwd.bak", "r") or exit("Unable to open passwd file!");

        while(!feof($file))
            {
                $user_line = fgets($file);
                $user_array = explode(":", $user_line);

                echo print_r( $user_array)."</br>";
            }
```

But what I got is:

```
Array ( [0] => misshary [1] => x [2] => 1002 [3] => 1003 [4] => Li Han,Li Han,, [5] =>      /home/misshary [6] => /bin/bash ) 1
Array ( [0] => testuser [1] => x [2] => 1003 [3] => 1004 [4] => test user,,, [5] => /home/testuser [6] => /bin/bash ) 1
Array ( [0] => ) 1
```

Why I got a extra line and result in a extra array `Array ( [0] => )` here?

P.S I understand why there is a extra 1 followed. My question is that why there are **three** arrays printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is no newline character at the end of your passwd file?

As for the extra `1` at the end its because you are printing the result of `print_r`

Since `print_r` already prints the array you should just use `print_r( $user_array)."</br>";` without the echo

As per the docs:

```
When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string. Otherwise, the return value is  TRUE.
```

Comment: I understand why there is a 1 followed. My question is that why there are three arrays printed?

Comment: Have you checked whether there is a blank line at the bottom of your passwd file?

Comment: That will basically cause `fgets` to return a blank line which explodes into a single element array with a single element

Comment: There's no blank line, I'm sure. And you can also see the line number above, that's all I have in that file.

Comment: `fgets` might be eating the EOF and returning false given some of the comments at http://us2.php.net/fgets.  Perhaps try restructuring it as `while ($user_line = fgets($file))`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you did `echo print_r( $user_array)`, `print_r` already did print the data out and no need to use echo.

print_r:

> When the return parameter is TRUE, this function will return a string.
>   Otherwise, the return value is TRUE.

so you echo the result of print_r, which is true and converted into 1.

And you may **skip the empty lines and ignore the new lines** in the file by using **[file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)** function:

```
$lines = file('/path/passwd.bak', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if (!$lines) {
  exit("Unable to open passwd file!");
}

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $user_array = explode(":", $line);
  var_dump($user_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using file instead of fopen solves the problem.